I can't figure out how to deploy a flask app with firebase as the database on render
I'm trying to deploy on render my python flask app that uses firebase as the database. The problem is: I don't know how to upload the credentials.json. I know i am not supposed to have that in my git repository but it doesn't contain any important data so I just uploaded it and it worked, it deploys. The problem is that the credentials were disabled for being exposed, according to google, so my app doesn't work.
I am willing to try another hosting platform but I think the same problem will appear, and maybe it's not that complicated but it's the first time I am deploying something so...thanks in advance
I've tried to make it a environment variable on render but it doesn't work. I keep having this error on the render console:
from config import app 
File "/opt/render/project/src/config.py", line 21, 
  in <module> cred = credentials.Certificate(cred_path) 
File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/firebase_admin/credentials.py", line 83, 
  in __init__ with open(cert) as json_file: 
^^^^^^^^^^ OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long: 

In my .env file, I access the json with the credentials path:
GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS=C:/Users/a/OneDrive/Desktop/BIBLIOTECA/credentials/credBiblioteca.json     

This is my config.py, where I have to use those credentials:
import firebase_admin from flask 
import Flask from firebase_admin 
import credentials, firestore, storage 
import os  

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates') 
app.secret_key = 'mysecretkey'  
#Carga del certificado del proyecto 
cred = credentials.Certificate("credentials/credBiblioteca.json")  #Inicializa la aplicación Firebase con las credenciales 
firebase_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'storageBucket': 'biblioteca.appspot.com'}) 
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "credentials/credBiblioteca.json" #Inicializa el cliente de Firestore 
db = firestore.client()  #Inicializa el bucket de almacenamiento 
bucket = storage.bucket(app=firebase_app)  

